How to change the line type of plot for Decision Curve Analysis in R dcurves package
First, I found the way to change color as following.
require(dcurves)
p <-
  dca(cancer ~ cancerpredmarker, data = df_binary) %>%
  plot(smooth = TRUE, show_ggplot_code = TRUE)
p + ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values = c('black', 'grey', 'purple'))

However, I tried the scale_linetype_manual, it does work.
How can I change the linetype?

As you set show_ggplot_code = TRUE in plot(), look at the plot-generating {ggplot2}-code printed to your Console and adapt stat_smooth() accordingly. For demonstration, we choose linetype = "dashed":
library(dcurves)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)

dca(cancer ~ cancerpredmarker, data = df_binary)  %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(net_benefit)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = threshold, y = net_benefit, color = label)) +
  stat_smooth(method = "loess", se = FALSE, formula = "y ~ x", 
              span = 0.2, linetype = "dashed") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.014, 0.14)) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1)) +
  labs(x = "Threshold Probability", y = "Net Benefit", color = "") +
  theme_bw()


Note. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dcurves/vignettes/dca.html
Update
Adressing your question in the comments below,

Is there a way to set different line type for three lines?

investigate
library(dcurves)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)

dca(cancer ~ cancerpredmarker, data = df_binary)  %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(net_benefit)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = threshold, y = net_benefit, color = label)) +
  stat_smooth(aes(linetype = label), 
              method = "loess", se = FALSE, formula = "y ~ x", span = .2) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.014, 0.14)) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1)) +
  labs(x = "Threshold Probability", y = "Net Benefit", color = "", linetype = "") +
  theme_bw()



Thank you very much. Is there a way to set different line type for three lines?
